# The world is like a Mirror: smile and it'll sɯıןǝ qɐɔʞ

Tags: code-golf, string

**Input:**

A string only containing the following characters:
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.?!` (space at the end) and two special characters (`_` and `|`)

**Output:**

Mirror the text based on the position(s) of the `_` and `|`.
`_` mirrors horizontally and `|` mirrors vertically.

**Mirroring process**

- The first `_` indicates the start of the mirroring of that substring, the second `_` the end.
- If just one `_` is present, you can continue on until the end of the string.
- If more then two `_` are present, the same process repeats.
- There can only be one `|` in the string, and this reversed the first substring and removes the second substring.

---

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.?!` (space at the end) will be converted to [`ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_of_text#Upside-down_text) (space at the end) when it is mirrored by `_` (click the link for the unicode values - requires unicode v8.0+).

*Example input 1:* `_Will I be mirrored?!`
*Output 1:* `Mıll I qǝ ɯıɹɹoɹǝp¿¡`

*Example input 2:* `Wi_ll I be mi_rrored?!`
*Output 2:* `Will I qǝ ɯırrored?!`

---

When it is mirrored by `|` we simply reverse the substring from 0 to index-of-`|`.

*Example input 1:* `Will I be mirror|ed?!`
*Output 1:* `Will I be mirrorrorrim eb I lliW`

Both mirrors (`_` and `|`) can be present in the string.

---

**General rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

**Test cases:**

```
_Will I be mirrored?!                          ->   Mıll I qǝ ɯıɹɹoɹǝp¿¡
Wi_ll I be mi_rrored?!                         ->   Will I qǝ ɯırrored?!
Will I be mirror|ed?!                          ->   Will I be mirrorrorrim eb I lliW
This_ is a test_ cont_aining bo|t_h mirrors.   ->   This ıs ɐ ʇǝsʇ contɐıuıuɓ qooq ɓuıuıɐtnoc ʇsǝʇ ɐ sı sihT
0_1_2_3_4_5|_6_7_8_9                           ->   0⇂2Ɛ4ϛϛ4Ɛ2⇂0
```

Comment: *feature request* -- Change the title to "The world is like a Mirror: smile and it'll sɯıןǝ qɐɔʞ" ;-)

Comment: @TimmyD ᗡouǝ ;)

Comment: @TimmyD In my country mirrors work like this: "smile ɘlimƨ", not "smile sɯıןǝ" :)  The title should be "The world is like a Mirror: smile and it'll ɘlimƨ back"

Comment: In the first line you should probably mention that spaces can appear in the input, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth - 174 bytes

Can prolly save with base compression or something cuz of unicode(this is only 119 chars)

```
u?qH\_&=hZG+G@@c2K+s+rB;1UT".?! ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡ "ZxKH?}\|zs_Bhcz\|zk
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3FqH%5C_%26%3DhZG%2BG%40%40c2K%2Bs%2BrB%3B1UT%22.%3F%21+%C9%90q%C9%94p%C7%9D%C9%9F%C9%93%C9%A5%C4%B1%C9%BE%CA%9El%C9%AFuodb%C9%B9s%CA%87n%CA%8C%CA%8Dx%CA%8Ez%E2%88%80%F0%90%90%92%C6%86%E1%97%A1%C6%8E%E2%84%B2%E2%85%81HI%C5%BF%E2%8B%8A%E2%85%82WNO%D4%80%CE%8C%E1%B4%9AS%E2%8A%A5%E2%88%A9%CE%9BMX%E2%85%84Z0%E2%87%82%E1%98%94%C6%90%DF%88%CF%9B9%E3%84%A586%CB%99%C2%BF%C2%A1+%22ZxKH%3F%7D%5C%7Czs_Bhcz%5C%7Czk&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=_Will+I+be+mirrored%3F%21%0AWi_ll+I+be+mi_rrored%3F%21%0AWill+I+be+mirror%7Ced%3F%21%0AThis_+is+a+test_+cont_aining+bo%7Ct_h+mirrors.%0A0_1_2_3_4_5%7C_6_7_8_9&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 308 bytes

```js
s=>s[r='replace'](/_.*?(_|$)/g,m=>m[r](/./g,c=>'| ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡'['| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.?!B'.indexOf(c)]||''))[r](/(.*)\|.*/,(m,t)=>t+[...t].reverse().join``)
```

### Test

```js
var solution =

s=>
  s[r='replace'](/_.*?(_|$)/g,m=>
    m[r](/./g,c=>
      '| ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡'
        ['| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.?!B'
          .indexOf(c)]||''
    )
  )
  [r](/(.*)\|.*/,(m,t)=>t+[...t].reverse().join``)

var testCases = [
  '_Will I be mirrored?!',
  'Wi_ll I be mi_rrored?!',
  'Will I be mirror|ed?!',
  'This_ is a test_ cont_aining bo|t_h mirrors.',
  '0_1_2_3_4_5|_6_7_8_9'
];
tests.textContent = testCases.map((c) => c + '   =>   ' + solution(c)).join('\n');
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="result.textContent=solution(this.value)" value="This_ is a test_ cont_aining bo|t_h mirrors." /><pre id="result"></pre><pre id="tests"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## PERL 243

242 + 1 for -p

```
$h=(split'\|',$_)[0];$_=$h.reverse$h if($_=~/\|/);for$b(split'_',$_){$b=~y/A-Za-z0-9.?!/ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡/ if($f);$\.=$b;$f=!$f;}$_='';
```

Ungolfed:

```
$reverse = (split('\|', $_))[0];
$_ = $reverse . reverse($reverse) if($_=~/\|/);

for $block (split '_', $_) {
    $block =~ y/A-Za-z0-9.?!/ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡/ if($flip);
    $\.=$block;
    $flip=!$flip;
}
$_='';
```

Example:

```
$ perl -p mirror.pl <<<'Will I be mirror|ed?!'
Will I be mirrorrorrim eb I lliW
```

I'm 99% sure this works, but most of the upsidedown characters don't display correctly on my system. I tested it by using a different range of character, e.g. `.?! -> %^&` instead of `.?! -> ˙¿¡`.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <strike>362</strike> <strike>362</strike> <strike>342</strike> 339 bytes

Edit 1: I found a bug in my original (failed if there were no `_` in input), fixed it, golfed some more, and I'm back at 362 where I started!

Edit 2: Golfed away 20 byes by replacing `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.?! "` with `paste(c(letters,LETTERS,0:9,".?! "),collapse="")`

Edit 3: Removing some extra whitespace shaves off another 3 bytes.

```
p=strsplit
l=length
i=p(readline(),"_")[[1]]
if(l(i)-1)i[v]=chartr(paste(c(letters,LETTERS,0:9,".?! "),collapse=""),"ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡ ",i[v<-seq(2,l(i),2)])
i=unlist(p(i,""))
if(l(b<-which(i=="|")-1))i[1:b+b]=rev(i[1:b])
cat(i,sep="")
```

Explained:

```
p=strsplit               # Aliases for common functions
l=length
i=p(readline(),"_")[[1]] # Read input, split by _s. Now every even-indexed substring is one that we must
                         # mirror vertically. (R indexes from 1.)
if(l(i)-1)               # If there are any _s,
  i[v]=chartr("paste(c(letters,LETTERS,0:9,".?! "),collapse=""),
  "ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡ ",
  i[v<-seq(2, l(i), 2)]
)                 # Flip the characters in the vertically-mirrored substrings
i=unlist(p(i,"")) # Split each substring into a single character object
if(l(b<-which(i=="|")-1)) # If there is a |,
  i[1:b+b]=rev(i[1:b])    # insert the reversed characters at the end of the list
cat(i,sep="")             # Print output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES5), <strike>344</strike> 340 bytes

```
function mirror(a){d=[];~a.indexOf("|")&&(a=a.split("|")[0]+a.split("|")[0].split("").reverse().join(""));for(var c=!1,b=0;b<a.length;++b)"_"==a[b]&&(c=!c),d[b]=c?"zʎxʍʌnʇsɹbdouɯlʞɾᴉɥɓɟǝpɔqɐZ⅄XMΛ∩⊥SᴚΌԀONW⅂⋊ſIH⅁ℲƎᗡƆᗺⱯ068ㄥ95߈Ɛᘔ⇂˙¿¡ "["zyxwvutsrqponmlkijhgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPNOMLKIJHGFEDCBA0987654321.?! ".indexOf(a[b])]:a[b];return d.join("")}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function mirror_u(s){return "zʎxʍʌnʇsɹbdouɯlʞɾᴉɥɓɟǝpɔqɐZ⅄XMΛ∩⊥SᴚΌԀONW⅂⋊ſIH⅁ℲƎᗡƆᗺⱯ068ㄥ95߈Ɛᘔ⇂˙¿¡ "["zyxwvutsrqponmlkijhgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPNOMLKIJHGFEDCBA0987654321.?! ".indexOf(s)]};

function mirror(str){var b=[];
if(~str.indexOf("|"))str=str.split("|")[0]+str.split("|")[0].split("").reverse().join("");
    var is_mirrored=false;
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;++i){
        if(str[i]=="_")is_mirrored=!is_mirrored;
        if(is_mirrored){b[i]=mirror_u(str[i])}else{b[i]=str[i]};
    }
    return b.join("");
}
```

EDIT: Longer working code, that is mirrored | by character 341.

```
function mirror(a){d=[];~a.indexOf("|")&&(a=a.split("|")[0]+a.split("|")[0].split("").reverse().join(""));for(var c=!1,b=0;b<a.length;++b)"_"==a[b]&&(c=!c),d[b]=c?"zʎxʍʌnʇsɹbdouɯlʞɾᴉɥɓɟǝpɔqɐZ⅄XMΛ∩⊥SᴚΌԀONW⅂⋊ſIH⅁ℲƎᗡƆᗺⱯ068ㄥ95߈Ɛᘔ⇂˙¿¡ "["zyxwvutsrqponmlkijhgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPNOMLKIJHGFEDCBA0987654321.?! ".indexOf(a[b])]:a[b];return d.join("")}//})""(nioj.d nruter;]b[a:])]b[a(fOxedni." !?.1234567890ABCDEFGHJIKLMONPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[" ¡¿˙⇂ᘔƐ߈59ㄥ860ⱯᗺƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Zɐqɔpǝɟɓɥᴉɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz"?c=]b[d,)c!=c(&&]b[a=="_")b++;htgnel.a<b;0=b,1!=c rav(rof;))""(nioj.)(esrever.)""(tilps.]0[)"|"(tilps.a+]0[)"|"(tilps.a=a(&&)"|"(fOxedni.a~;][=d{)a(rorrim noitcnuf
```

Comment: The `` character takes up two UTF-16 code units, but you don't seem to be taking this into account. Does the `W` in the first test case come out correctly?

Comment: The characters are all UTF-8. All test cases give the correct output.

Comment: Oh, it seems you're using code point `U+15FA` for the upside-down B. The one in the challenge is code point `U+10412`.

Comment: I used the characters from the linked wikipedia page, I just copied them into my editor.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 176 bytes

```
\|.+
:$`
O$^`:|(?!^)\G.

:

T`w.?!`_0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86∀:ƆᗡƎℲ⅁\HIſ⋊⅂WN\OԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Zɐqɔ\pǝɟɓɥıɾʞ\lɯu\o\dbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz˙¿¡`_[^_]*_?
:
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApcfC4rCjokYApPJF5gOnwoPyFeKVxHLgoKOgoKVGB3Lj8hYF8w4oeC4ZiUxpDfiM-bOeOEpTg24oiAOsaG4Zehxo7ihLLihYFcSEnFv-KLiuKFgldOXE_UgM6M4bSaU-KKpeKIqc6bTVjihYRayZBxyZRccMedyZ_Jk8mlxLHJvsqeXGzJr3Vcb1xkYsm5c8qHbsqMyo14yo56y5nCv8KhYF9bXl9dKl8_CjoK8JCQkg&input=X1dpbGwgSSBiZSBtaXJyb3JlZD8hCldpX2xsIEkgYmUgbWlfcnJvcmVkPyEKV2lsbCBJIGJlIG1pcnJvcnxlZD8hClRoaXNfIGlzIGEgdGVzdF8gY29udF9haW5pbmcgYm98dF9oIG1pcnJvcnMuCjBfMV8yXzNfNF81fF82XzdfOF85) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>504</s> 502 bytes

```
import java.util.*;String c(String s){Map m=new HashMap();int i=0,j;while(i<67)m.put("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.?! ".charAt(i),"ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡ ".charAt(i++));String q=s.split("\\|")[0],z[]=(q+(s.equals(q)?"":new StringBuffer(q).reverse()+"")).split("_"),r="";for(i=-1;++i<z.length;){q="";for(char c:z[i].toCharArray())q+=m.get(c);r+=i%2<1?z[i]:q;}return r;}
```

Of course I'll have to answer my own challenge again. And.. it's long.. xD

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/RdF4se)

```
import java.util.*;
class M{
  static String c(String s){
    Map m = new HashMap();
    int i = 0,
        j;
    while(i < 67){
      m.put("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.?! ".charAt(i),
          "ɐqɔpǝɟɓɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ƆᗡƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WNOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ΛMX⅄Z0⇂ᘔƐ߈ϛ9ㄥ86˙¿¡ ".charAt(i++));
    }
    String q = s.split("\\|")[0],
           z[] = (q + (s.equals(q)
                        ? ""
                        : new StringBuffer(q).reverse() + "")
                 ).split("_"),
           r = "";
    for(i = -1; ++i < z.length;){
      q = "";
      for(char c : z[i].toCharArray()){
        q += m.get(c);
      }
      r += i%2 < 1
            ? z[i]
            : q;
    }
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("_Will I be mirrored?!"));
    System.out.println(c("Wi_ll I be mi_rrored?!"));
    System.out.println(c("Will I be mirror|ed?!"));
    System.out.println(c("This_ is a test_ cont_aining bo|t_h mirrors."));
    System.out.println(c("0_1_2_3_4_5|_6_7_8_9"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Mıll I qǝ ɯıɹɹoɹǝp¿¡
Will I qǝ ɯırrored?!
Will I be mirrorrorrim eb I lliW
This ıs ɐ ʇǝsʇ contɐıuıuɓ qooq ɓuıuıɐtnoc ʇsǝʇ ɐ sı sihT
0⇂2Ɛ4ϛϛ4Ɛ2⇂0
```

Comment: Suggest dropping the `j` variable.